# In assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, element

I input 'test' as the string, phrase, and it gives me the following error:

```
    >> CreateBarcodePattern('test')
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in CreateBarcodePattern (line 5)
    p(i) = code128B{find(ismember(code128B,phrase(i)))-109,3};
```

The function CreateBarcodePattern is as follows:

```
function [p] = CreateBarcodePattern(phrase)
load('code128B');
p = [];
for i = 1:length(phrase)
    p(i) = code128B{find(ismember(code128B,phrase(i)))-109,3};
end
```

I put a break point at line 5 and at the point i = 1, p = [] (and empty array so far), code128B = <108x3 cell> (A 108 by 3 cell full of strings), and phrase = 'test'.
The very next line gives me the error above.
I tried doing:

```
load('code128B.mat')
p = [];
phrase = 'test';
p(1) = find(ismember(code128B,phrase(1)))-109;
p(1) = code128B{p(1),3}
```

but at the last line the error:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B
and I must be the same.
```

is again given. Right before the error, `p = 84` which is what I am expecting, this is due to the previous line, `p(1) = fi...`
The line:

```
code128B{find(ismember(code128B,'t'))-109,3};
```

Returns the correct variable so I know this much works. It just doesn't work when I'm iterating it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also, I tried changeing the code to for i = 1:length(code128B) which should make the number of elements in I and B the same but I still get the same error. Even though this wont work as soon as i > 4 as phrase = 'test' which is 4 characters long.

Comment: What is code128B.mat?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the line

```
find(ismember(code128B,phrase(1)))
```

is returning more than 1 index. p(1) wants exactly one element.

If you just want the first index, then do something like this:

```
Idx = find(ismember(code128B,phrase(1)));
Idx = sort(Idx); % Am just assuming you need to sort!
p(1) = Idx(1) - 109;
p(1) = code128B{p(1),3}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `find(x,1)` for the finding first one, or in this case `find(ismember(code128B,phrase(1)),1)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
p(i) = code128B{find(ismember(code128B,phrase(i)))-109,3};
p(i) = str2num(code128B{find(ismember(code128B,phrase(i)))-109,3});
```